# Filter on signal edge in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java2

Given

`Observable.just(false, true, true, false, false, true, false);`

How can a new observable be created such that it only emits a value when the source observable transitions from false to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source.distinctUntilChanged().filter(x -> x).map(x -> "false -> true")`

`distinctUntilChanged` removes adjacent duplicates, `filter` leaves only true values.

If the source observable can start with a true value, and it must not be interpreted as a transition, add `skipWhile(x -> x)` before the `distinctUntilChanged`.